# How to find subgame perfect equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory

We are given that normal form
[image]

If this game is repeated two times (t=1, 2), then find
(1) subgame perfect equilibrium and (2) one Nash equilibrium that is not the subgame perfect equilibrium.

---

Actually, I can solve the problem if the game is done only one time, however, I cannot know how to solve when the game plays two times.

Comment: The twice-repeated game has more than one SPE. Are you ok with just one (as the singular suggests) or are you looking for the whole set?

Comment: @mlc I want to know the method of finding the whole set of SPE for this problem.

Comment: SPE implies that you have to play a NE of the stage game in the second period. Given that you can solve the one-shot game, perhaps you can provide some context by writing down *all* the NE for the one-shot game in your OP. (Hint: there are three of those.)