# Is there one more subgame perfect equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory

[image]
The problem is when P1 choose $A$, they play a game as described in normal form, and when P1 choose $B$, then P2 can choose $a$ or $b$.

I think the Nash equilibria of the Game are $\{U,L\}$ and $\{M,C\}$.

Looking at the subgame that P1 chose $A$, both equilibria gives the payoff to P1 less than the case when P1 chose $B$.

Also, looking at the subgame that P1 chose $B$, P2 will choose $a$.

Thus, I think $\{(A,U), L\}$, $\{(A,M), C\}$, and $\{B, a\}$ are Nash equilibria, and only the $\{B,a\}$ is the subgame perfect equilibirum.
However, the problem says "find two subgame perfect equilibria." 
Are there any wrong things?

Comment: $\{(A,U),L \}$ and $\{ (A,M),C \}$ are not Nash equilibrium *outcomes*, because player $1$ always has a profitable deviation. (Note the distinction between an equilibrium outcome and an equilibrium; none of what you have written are equilibria.) $\{ M,C \}$ is not a NE of the subgame following player $1$ choosing $A$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I mean the $\{M,C\}$ is an equilibrium for the game described by normal form. So, can you explain what are the subgame perfect equilibria? I believe $\{B, a\}$ must be a subgame perfect equilibrium, isn't it?

Comment: doesn’t player $1$ have a profitable deviation to $D$ when player $2$ plays $C$ in this subgame (the game you show in normal form)?

Comment: Ah, there you go. You’ve changed the payoff matrix.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Very sorry, I wrote wrong of (D,C)'s payoff, so I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This game has two (pure-strategy) sub-game perfect equilibria that induce the same equilibrium outcome: $\{(B,U),(a,L) \}$ and $\{(B,M),(a,C) \}$. The first pair in each equilibrium specifies player $1$'s strategy while the second pair specifies player $2$'s strategy (in hopefully the obvious way).

Recall that an equilibrium is always a profile of strategies, and the strategies are **fully-contingent** plans that determine actions even off the equilibrium path.

In particular, as I suggest in my comment above, $\{B,a\}$ is an equilibrium outcome but not an equilibrium. It does not specify what actions players $1$ and $2$ take in the event that player $1$ initially chose the action $A$ (even if we know this will never happen in this equilibrium).

Comment: Can you explain the statement $\{B,a\}$ is an equilibrium outcome but not an equilibrium. Actually, I do not know the difference between them. Also, you said this game has two sub-game perfect equilibria but did not wrote them. Can I ask you what they are?

Comment: @Danny_Kim See my edit. To understand why $\{B,a\}$ is not an equilibrium, recall that according to the definition of an equilibrium, an equilibrium specifies a profile of strategies. $\{B,a\}$ is not a profile of strategies. For more details on this, please see any standard game theory reference.

Comment: Very thank you, your answer gives me very huge intuition and idea. I am going to buy a textbook as soon as possible!! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. You may also find the [Economics SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) of interest.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking too much, can you see one more my question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486210/how-to-find-subgame-perfect-equilibrium